# RMAN not starting

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

When I try to start RMAN I get this error:

```
 SQL> rman target=/
 SP2-0734: unknown command beginning "rman targe..." - rest of line ignored.
 SQL>
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't run RMAN from SQL*Plus - you run it from the command line.  [Have a look here](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/backup.102/b14193/toc.htm#i771020).

Answer (score 0):

You must run the RMAN from command line interface not from the sql plus. The following are the command options.

1).  RMAN target / catalog username/password@schema
2.)  RMAN
     connect target /

Answer (score 0):

Hey DCookie is right but you can start rman from SQL Plus prompt with following command:

```
SQL > !rman target /
```

The first character `!` represents an OS level command.  So you don't need to come out from SQL prompt to connect to RMAN.

Comment: That one returns SP2-0734: unknown command beginning on my machine [ Win2008, ORA 11-R2 ]